# MYSQL - GROUP_CONCAT AND FIND_IN_SET are mixing values/order?

Tags: mysql, group-concat, find-in-set

I have the following problem: I try to select all the votes a user made and put them out in one column. I use `GROUP_CONCAT` for this, but somehow it is mixing the values order.

This is the SQL code:

```
SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT options.option_name SEPARATOR ',') AS selected,
    user_login.firstname, user_login.lastname,
    event.event_title
FROM
    options, user_login, event, votes, questions
WHERE
    event.id = ? AND questions.Event_id = event.id 
    AND votes.user_id = user_login.id AND votes.question_id = questions.id 
    AND FIND_IN_SET(options.id, selected)
```

GROUP BY 
        user_login.id
   ORDER BY 
        user_login.class

An example value for votes would be:

```
id |  event_id  | question_id  |  selected   |  user_id
25       14           42          52,46,41         1
26       14           43             68            1
```

Options is like:

```
id |  option_name   | question_id
 40        Project A          42
 41        Project B          42
 46        Project C          42     
 52        Project D          42
 67        Hello              43
 68        Bye                43
```

Questions is like:

```
id  |  question_name  | event_id
42     Project Number       14
43     Greeting             14
```

Event is like:

```
id  |  title
14     Project Testing
```

And the output of the given code is:

```
selected                            |  event_title
Project C, Bye, ProjectD, Project B      Test
```

How can I keep the original order, so that it outputs me:
Project D, Project C, Project B, Bye?

Comment: can you provide some actual data? like the data that would correspond to your desired output?

Comment: I have added some real data

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

would something like this work? basically you say order by the field values and make them look like '52','46',... etc.

```
SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT options.option_name 
                 ORDER BY FIELD( options.id, 
                                 concat('"', 
                                        replace(selected, ',', '","'),
                                        '"') 
                               ) 
                 SEPARATOR ','
                ) AS selected,
    user_login.firstname, user_login.lastname,
    event.event_title
FROM options, user_login, event, votes, questions
WHERE event.id = ? AND questions.Event_id = event.id 
  AND votes.user_id = user_login.id AND votes.question_id = questions.id 
  AND FIND_IN_SET(options.id, selected)
GROUP BY user_login.id
ORDER BY user_login.class
```

---

**EDIT:**

my preferred way to do this is to make a variable that has the string.. its easier to read and you can ensure it does the correct order this way..

```
SET @order_field := (
    SELECT 
        group_concat(
            CONCAT('"', replace(selected, ',', '","'), '"')
        ) 
    FROM votes);
```

then the query would be a lot easier to read...

```
SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT options.option_name 
                 ORDER BY FIELD( options.id, @order_field) 
                 SEPARATOR ','
                ) AS selected,
    user_login.firstname, user_login.lastname,
    event.event_title
FROM options, user_login, event, votes, questions
WHERE event.id = ? AND questions.Event_id = event.id 
  AND votes.user_id = user_login.id AND votes.question_id = questions.id 
  AND FIND_IN_SET(options.id, selected)
GROUP BY user_login.id
ORDER BY user_login.class
```

Comment: This has somehow the same output as my query had:

Comment: @BufferOverflow  did you try it with the variable? worked on my end

Comment: I had to replace o.id with options id and then I tried out the query but the output is the same as mentioned previously.

Comment: @BufferOverflow hmm not sure why its different on your end from mine. i was getting the correct result. maybe it has something to do with your users table?

Comment: @BufferOverflow try writing them in manually and see if that works.. aka `ORDER BY FIELD( orders.id, 52,46,41,68)`

Comment: It worked with some modification: `ORDER BY votes.id, FIELD [...] replace(votes.selected[...]`. Thanks!

Comment: @BufferOverflow ah was pretty close! glad I could help :)